# Recursive CTE listing all ancestors as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I found many examples that show recursive CTEs that will list the path as a concatenated string and the depth of the level. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
    (ID varchar(20),
    ParentID varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Test values ('100000','HEAD');
INSERT INTO #Test values ('100100','100000');
INSERT INTO #Test values ('100200','100100');
INSERT INTO #Test values ('100300','100200');
INSERT INTO #Test values ('100400','100300');


;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, ParentID, cast(ID as varchar(100)) as path, 0 AS Level
    FROM #Test
    WHERE ParentID = 'HEAD' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Id,t.ParentID, cast(cte.path +'>'+ t.ID as varchar(100)),   Level + 1
    FROM #Test t
    INNER JOIN CTE ON t.ParentID = CTE.ID
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
DROP table #Test
```

Is there a way to return each ancestor in each row in a separate column? So instead of the current result:

```
ID      ParentId Path                               Level
100000  HEAD     100000                             0
100100  100000   100000>100100                      1
100200  100100   100000>100100>100200               2
100300  100200   100000>100100>100200>100300        3
100400  100300   100000>100100>100200>100300>100400 4
```

It would be:

```
Id      Parent  L0        L1     L2     L3     L4
100000  HEAD    100000    Null   Null   Null   Null
100100  100000  100000    100100 Null   Null   Null
100200  100100  100000    100100 100200 Null   Null
100300  100200  100000    100100 100200 100300 Null 
100400  100300  100000    100100 100200 100300 100400
```

Assumption is that I know the max level of depth, in this example the max level is 5. SQL Server ver. 12.0, and DB Compatibility is at 120.

Comment: You need to know the maximum number of levels in advance.  That is why a single string is typically used.

Comment: I'll update the question with the assumption I do know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a known or maximum number of levels, consider a bit of JSON.

If not 2016+ ... there is a similar XML approach.

**Example**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, ParentID, cast(ID as varchar(100)) as path, 0 AS Level
    FROM #Test
    WHERE ParentID = 'HEAD' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Id,t.ParentID, cast(cte.path +'>'+ t.ID as varchar(100)),   Level + 1
    FROM #Test t
    INNER JOIN CTE ON t.ParentID = CTE.ID
)
SELECT A.ID
      ,A.ParentID
      ,B.*
      ,A.Level
  FROM CTE A
  Cross Apply (
                Select L0 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]'))
                      ,L1 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]'))
                      ,L2 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]'))
                      ,L3 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[3]'))
                      ,L4 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[4]'))
                      ,L5 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[5]'))
                 From  ( values ( '["'+replace(path,'>','","')+'"]' ) ) A(S)
              ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

**UPDATE:  The XML Approach**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, ParentID, cast(ID as varchar(100)) as path, 0 AS Level
    FROM #Test
    WHERE ParentID = 'HEAD' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Id,t.ParentID, cast(cte.path +'>'+ t.ID as varchar(100)),   Level + 1
    FROM #Test t
    INNER JOIN CTE ON t.ParentID = CTE.ID
)
SELECT A.ID
      ,A.ParentID
      ,B.*
      ,A.Level
  FROM CTE A
  Cross Apply (
               Select  L0 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(50)')
                      ,L1 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
                      ,L2 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(50)')
                      ,L3 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(50)')
                      ,L4 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(50)')
                      ,L5 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(50)')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(Path,'>','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
              ) B
```

Comment: SQL Server v12. Unfortunately no JSON_VALUE()

Comment: @LukeD See UPDATE: The XML Approach

Answer (score 0):

as everyone mentioned you need to know number of levels you have , but here is the implementation with `PIVOT`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, ParentID, cast(ID as varchar(100)) as path, 0 AS Level
    FROM #Test
    WHERE ParentID = 'HEAD' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Id,t.ParentID, cast(cte.path +'>'+ t.ID as varchar(100)),   Level + 1
    FROM #Test t
    INNER JOIN CTE ON t.ParentID = CTE.ID
)
select 
*
from (
    Select Id , ParentID,
    'L'+ CAST(Row_Number() Over (Partition By ID Order By ID) AS VARCHAR)AS Col,
    Split.value 
    , level
    From CTE
    Cross apply string_split(path,'>') as Split
) AS tbl
Pivot (Max(value) For Col IN ([L1],[L2],[L3],[L4],[L5])) AS Pvt
```

Comment: DB Compatibility is 120, so no string_split()